Seeking someone for asynchronous interview over email
I am currently an undergraduate at Michigan State University enrolled in an honors research seminar on Circular Economy. I am doing a research project on ways to transition the lifestyle of electronics, like phones, computers, and data centers to a circular process.
I would like to ask some
questions relating to circularity, specifically in the electronic
industry. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to answer a few questions on another platform.

Hi. I'm not sure if this question is suitable for this site, probably it'll get closed. But to help you, I'd recommend you to contact the researchers in the area you're interested directly. Many researchers have a personal webpage with contact information, and are willing to answer emails.

Should "lifestyle" perhaps be "lifecycle"?

I'm sure there are people on Amazon Mechanical Turk who  are willing to answer your questions/survey for a modest fee.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about economics per se.
